# Fragment identifier in form action attribute

Tags: html, forms, fragment-identifier

I have a form which I'd like to post to the same page. The form action contains a fragment identifier for the element on the page that contains it - what I want it to do is post the data, then reload the same page at the same point so the user doesn't need to scroll down.

example index.php:

```
<div>
  some very long content that pushes my form down the page
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  <form action="index.php#myDiv" method="post">
    <input name="abc" value="123"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

However I have a couple of problems - firstly I'm not sure if this is good practice and can't find much on what *is* considered good practice with fragment identifiers.

Second, some others have said that sometimes the form "jumps to the top" when they click submit. I haven't been able to reproduce this yet but it seems pretty obvious that instead of posting the data, the browser is going with the fragment identifier action instead.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the user after the form submission using header() function along with identifier.

```
<div>
  some very long content that pushes my form down the page
</div>
/*Use header() to redirect the person on the #point*/
<?php
//form data goes here, if it passes everything then use
header('Location:index.php#myDiv');
exit;
?>
<div id="myDiv">
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="abc" value="123"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```